# customize Image path and Text through properties file

Tags: jsf-2

i need to be able to customize LogoImage and Text to be displayed in my jsf2 application header .
the Image path and Text value is supposed to be placed in a properties file , the application should be able to load these properties and startup and use'em in my JSF header .
any idea on how to acheive this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put it in a resourcebundle:

faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>/Bundle</base-name>
        <var>bundle</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

Bundle.properties, located in src/main/resources:

```
imageurl=img/logo.png
applicationname=My app
```

Xhtml:

```
<h:graphicImage name="#{bundle.imageurl}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.applicationname}"/>
```

logo.png is located in webapp/resources/img/.

I'm using Netbeans 8, don't know if the location of files are the same in Eclipse.